# Events calendar- show the events in popup

Tags: android, events, calendar, popupwindow

I'm making a customize calendar and also displaying the events..

What i need is?
Right now im displaying the events in textview below the calendar. I need to display the events in popup.. 
How to implement this? Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks a lot in advance..

CalendarView.java

```
public class CalendarView extends Activity {

    public GregorianCalendar month, itemmonth;// calendar instances.

    public CalendarAdapter adapter;// adapter instance
    public Handler handler;// for grabbing some event values for showing the dot
                            // marker.
    public ArrayList<String> items; // container to store calendar items which
                                    // needs showing the event marker
    ArrayList<String> event;
    LinearLayout rLayout;
    ArrayList<String> date;
    ArrayList<String> desc;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.calendar);
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);

        rLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.text);
        month = (GregorianCalendar) GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
        itemmonth = (GregorianCalendar) month.clone();

        items = new ArrayList<String>();

        adapter = new CalendarAdapter(this, month);

        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(adapter);

        handler = new Handler();
        handler.post(calendarUpdater);

        TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
        title.setText(android.text.format.DateFormat.format("MMMM yyyy", month));

        RelativeLayout previous = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.previous);

        previous.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setPreviousMonth();
                refreshCalendar();
            }
        });

        RelativeLayout next = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.next);
        next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setNextMonth();
                refreshCalendar();

            }
        });

        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {
                // removing the previous view if added
                if (((LinearLayout) rLayout).getChildCount() > 0) {
                    ((LinearLayout) rLayout).removeAllViews();
                }
                desc = new ArrayList<String>();
                date = new ArrayList<String>();
                ((CalendarAdapter) parent.getAdapter()).setSelected(v);
                String selectedGridDate = CalendarAdapter.dayString
                        .get(position);
                String[] separatedTime = selectedGridDate.split("-");
                String gridvalueString = separatedTime[2].replaceFirst("^0*",
                        "");// taking last part of date. ie; 2 from 2012-12-02.
                int gridvalue = Integer.parseInt(gridvalueString);
                // navigate to next or previous month on clicking offdays.
                if ((gridvalue > 10) && (position < 8)) {
                    setPreviousMonth();
                    refreshCalendar();
                } else if ((gridvalue < 7) && (position > 28)) {
                    setNextMonth();
                    refreshCalendar();
                }
                ((CalendarAdapter) parent.getAdapter()).setSelected(v);

                for (int i = 0; i < Utility.startDates.size(); i++) {
                    if (Utility.startDates.get(i).equals(selectedGridDate)) {
                        desc.add(Utility.nameOfEvent.get(i));
                    }
                }

                if (desc.size() > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < desc.size(); i++) {
                        TextView rowTextView = new TextView(CalendarView.this);

                        // set some properties of rowTextView or something
                        rowTextView.setText("Event:" + desc.get(i));
                        rowTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

                        // add the textview to the linearlayout
                        rLayout.addView(rowTextView);

                    }

                }

                desc = null;

            }

        });
    }

    protected void setNextMonth() {
        if (month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) == month
                .getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH)) {
            month.set((month.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR) + 1),
                    month.getActualMinimum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH), 1);
        } else {
            month.set(GregorianCalendar.MONTH,
                    month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) + 1);
        }

    }

    protected void setPreviousMonth() {
        if (month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) == month
                .getActualMinimum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH)) {
            month.set((month.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR) - 1),
                    month.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH), 1);
        } else {
            month.set(GregorianCalendar.MONTH,
                    month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) - 1);
        }

    }

    protected void showToast(String string) {
        Toast.makeText(this, string, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    public void refreshCalendar() {
        TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);

        adapter.refreshDays();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        handler.post(calendarUpdater); // generate some calendar items

        title.setText(android.text.format.DateFormat.format("MMMM yyyy", month));
    }

    public Runnable calendarUpdater = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            items.clear();

            // Print dates of the current week
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
            String itemvalue;
            event = Utility.readCalendarEvent(CalendarView.this);
            Log.d("=====Event====", event.toString());
            Log.d("=====Date ARRAY====", Utility.startDates.toString());

            for (int i = 0; i < Utility.startDates.size(); i++) {
                itemvalue = df.format(itemmonth.getTime());
                itemmonth.add(GregorianCalendar.DATE, 1);
                items.add(Utility.startDates.get(i).toString());
            }
            adapter.setItems(items);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}
```

CalendarAdapter.java

```
public class CalendarAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    private java.util.Calendar month;
    public GregorianCalendar pmonth; // calendar instance for previous month
    /**
     * calendar instance for previous month for getting complete view
     */
    public GregorianCalendar pmonthmaxset;
    private GregorianCalendar selectedDate;
    int firstDay;
    int maxWeeknumber;
    int maxP;
    int calMaxP;
    int lastWeekDay;
    int leftDays;
    int mnthlength;
    String itemvalue, curentDateString;
    DateFormat df;

    private ArrayList<String> items;
    public static List<String> dayString;
    private View previousView;

    public CalendarAdapter(Context c, GregorianCalendar monthCalendar) {
        CalendarAdapter.dayString = new ArrayList<String>();
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
        month = monthCalendar;
        selectedDate = (GregorianCalendar) monthCalendar.clone();
        mContext = c;
        month.set(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        this.items = new ArrayList<String>();
        df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
        curentDateString = df.format(selectedDate.getTime());
        refreshDays();
    }

    public void setItems(ArrayList<String> items) {
        for (int i = 0; i != items.size(); i++) {
            if (items.get(i).length() == 1) {
                items.set(i, "0" + items.get(i));
            }
        }
        this.items = items;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return dayString.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return dayString.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new view for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        TextView dayView;
        if (convertView == null) { // if it's not recycled, initialize some
                                    // attributes
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.calendar_item, null);

        }
        dayView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.date);
        // separates daystring into parts.
        String[] separatedTime = dayString.get(position).split("-");
        // taking last part of date. ie; 2 from 2012-12-02
        String gridvalue = separatedTime[2].replaceFirst("^0*", "");
        // checking whether the day is in current month or not.
        if ((Integer.parseInt(gridvalue) > 1) && (position < firstDay)) {
            // setting offdays to white color.
            dayView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            dayView.setClickable(false);
            dayView.setFocusable(false);
        } else if ((Integer.parseInt(gridvalue) < 7) && (position > 28)) {
            dayView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            dayView.setClickable(false);
            dayView.setFocusable(false);
        } else {
            // setting curent month's days in blue color.
            dayView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        }

        if (dayString.get(position).equals(curentDateString)) {
            setSelected(v);
            previousView = v;
        } else {
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item_background);
        }
        dayView.setText(gridvalue);

        // create date string for comparison
        String date = dayString.get(position);

        if (date.length() == 1) {
            date = "0" + date;
        }
        String monthStr = "" + (month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) + 1);
        if (monthStr.length() == 1) {
            monthStr = "0" + monthStr;
        }

        // show icon if date is not empty and it exists in the items array
        ImageView iw = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.date_icon);
        if (date.length() > 0 && items != null && items.contains(date)) {
            iw.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            iw.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        return v;
    }

    public View setSelected(View view) {
        if (previousView != null) {
            previousView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item_background);
        }
        previousView = view;
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calendar_cel_selectl);
        return view;
    }

    public void refreshDays() {
        // clear items
        items.clear();
        dayString.clear();
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
        pmonth = (GregorianCalendar) month.clone();
        // month start day. ie; sun, mon, etc
        firstDay = month.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        // finding number of weeks in current month.
        maxWeeknumber = month.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
        // allocating maximum row number for the gridview.
        mnthlength = maxWeeknumber * 7;
        maxP = getMaxP(); // previous month maximum day 31,30....
        calMaxP = maxP - (firstDay - 1);// calendar offday starting 24,25 ...
        /**
         * Calendar instance for getting a complete gridview including the three
         * month's (previous,current,next) dates.
         */
        pmonthmaxset = (GregorianCalendar) pmonth.clone();
        /**
         * setting the start date as previous month's required date.
         */
        pmonthmaxset.set(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, calMaxP + 1);

        /**
         * filling calendar gridview.
         */
        for (int n = 0; n < mnthlength; n++) {

            itemvalue = df.format(pmonthmaxset.getTime());
            pmonthmaxset.add(GregorianCalendar.DATE, 1);
            dayString.add(itemvalue);

        }
    }

    private int getMaxP() {
        int maxP;
        if (month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) == month
                .getActualMinimum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH)) {
            pmonth.set((month.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR) - 1),
                    month.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH), 1);
        } else {
            pmonth.set(GregorianCalendar.MONTH,
                    month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) - 1);
        }
        maxP = pmonth.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        return maxP;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added textview for each event, you should have added listview, instead and populated it with your events. Anyways for displaying it as popup you can use dialog and display a listview inside.
At first I would create a list layout... something like:

```
list_layout

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

         <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:divider="#b5b5b5"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
     </LinearLayout>
```

Then a simple TextView like:

single_item_layout

```
 <LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 

     <TextView android:id="@+id/singleItem"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="blue thingy"
        android:background="#336699" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and a simple main layout:

lastly a simple CalenderView Activity:

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
            // removing the previous view if added
            if (((LinearLayout) rLayout).getChildCount() > 0) {
                ((LinearLayout) rLayout).removeAllViews();
            }
            desc = new ArrayList<String>();
            date = new ArrayList<String>();
            ((CalendarAdapter) parent.getAdapter()).setSelected(v);
            String selectedGridDate = CalendarAdapter.dayString
                    .get(position);
            String[] separatedTime = selectedGridDate.split("-");
            String gridvalueString = separatedTime[2].replaceFirst("^0*",
                    "");// taking last part of date. ie; 2 from 2012-12-02.
            int gridvalue = Integer.parseInt(gridvalueString);
            // navigate to next or previous month on clicking offdays.
            if ((gridvalue > 10) && (position < 8)) {
                setPreviousMonth();
                refreshCalendar();
            } else if ((gridvalue < 7) && (position > 28)) {
                setNextMonth();
                refreshCalendar();
            }
            ((CalendarAdapter) parent.getAdapter()).setSelected(v);

            for (int i = 0; i < Utility.startDates.size(); i++) {
                if (Utility.startDates.get(i).equals(selectedGridDate)) {
                    desc.add(Utility.nameOfEvent.get(i));
                }
            }

        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(CalenderView.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.list_layout);
        dialog.setTitle("Events");
        ListView listView = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.list);

        ArrayAdapter<String> ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.single_item_layout ,  desc);//desc your string array 
        listView.setAdapter(ad);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                //do something on click
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
    }   
   desc=null;
}
```

and that's all.

Comment: shows error like this Syntax error on token "desc",VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token

Comment: i have edited.. change here:    

ArrayAdapter<String> ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.single_item_layout ,  desc);